# bind_param in mysqli is not working with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I was trying to learn MySqli prepared statements, but i got stuck in dynamic binding.

This is my code. this is working fine but i am getting all the results instead of **user_id=1**. not sure what i am missing here. please help me..

```
public function prepareSelectSql($from,$feilds="*",$where = '',$bind=false,$params)
{
    if($this->conn)
    {
        $query = "SELECT ".$feilds." FROM `".$from."`";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if($stmt === false) 
        {
            trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $this->conn->errno . ' ' . $this->conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        } 

        if($bind)
        {
            echo "<br/><br/>";
            echo $query .= $where;
            $id='1';//call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
            echo "<br/><br/>Here";
        }   

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            print_r($myrow);
        }

    }
    else { echo "Not Aavailable";}
}
```

i am calling this function as below.

```
$where = 'WHERE `ID`=?';
        $params = array('i','1');
        $feilds = '`user_nicename`';

        $this->db->prepareSelectSql('wp_users',$feilds,$where,true,$params);
```

Comment: What is being passed in? Give us all data so we can reproduce

Comment: @chris85 i have removed the passing arguments. I gave the id directly.. Also it get inside of the **if($bind)**.

Comment: you have prepared the statement and then you are adding the where clause to the query, and also there is no space between table name and where

Comment: You are appending your `WHERE` - `echo $query .= $where;` **after** you have already done your `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$bind` condition you concat your `SQL` but you prepare it before condition. I suggest you to prepare query after completing full query string.

```
$query = "SELECT ".$feilds." FROM `".$from."` ";

if($stmt === false){
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $this->conn->errno . ' ' . $this->conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

if($bind){
    $query .= $where;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $id = '1';
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
}else{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
}
```